# Bounded data means bounded solution to parabolic PDE

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $u_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega).$ Consider
$$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
$$u|_{\partial\Omega} = 0$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
or more generally replace $\Delta$ with a suitable elliptic operator $A$. How does one show that $u \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$?

(My question stems from this paper: http://www.mat.uniroma2.it/~porretta/papers/Blanchard-Porretta-JDE.pdf. See Theorem A.1 in the appendix (page 425). It is a different nonlinear equation but this should still be true).

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n,\,n\geqslant 2,$ be a bounded domain 
with Lipschitz boundary. For a cylinder $\,Q_T=\Omega\times(0,T),\,$ denote by 
$S_T$ its side surface $\partial\Omega\times (0,T)$, with notation $\Gamma_T$ 
standing for its parabolic boundary $\{(x,t)\colon\; x\in \overline{\Omega},t=0\}\cup S_T$. Obviously, solution $u$ to the inhomogeneous heat equation $\,u_t-\Delta u=f\,$ in $\,Q_T\,$ with  innhomogeneous boundary condition $u|_{S_T}=\psi$ can be represented 
in the form $u=v+w\,$  where
$$
\begin{cases}
v_t-\Delta v=0\;\;\text{in}\;\;Q_T\,,\\
v|_{\partial\Omega}=\psi,\quad t\in [0,T],\\
v|_{t=0}=u_0,\quad x\in\overline{\Omega},
\end{cases}
\qquad
\begin{cases}
w_t-\Delta w=f\;\;\text{in}\;\;Q_T\,,\\
w|_{\partial\Omega}=0,\quad t\in [0,T],\\
w|_{t=0}=0,\quad x\in\overline{\Omega}.
\end{cases}
$$
Let $v\in H^1(Q_T)$ be a weak solution satisfying the integral identity 
$$
\int\limits_{Q_T}v_t\varphi_t\,dxdt+\int\limits_{Q_T}\nabla v\cdot\nabla\varphi\,\,dxdt
=0\quad \forall\varphi\in H^1(Q_T)\colon\; \varphi|_{S_T}=0\tag{1}
$$
with initial and boundary conditions 
$$
v|_{t=0}=u_0\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(\Omega),\quad v|_{S_T}=\psi\in H^{\frac{1}{2}}(S_T).
$$
For solution $v$, denote $m\overset{\rm def}{=}
\underset{\Gamma_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{v}\,$  
with the finite essential supremum taken over parabolic boundary $\Gamma_T\,$ 
*w.r.t.*  the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue mesure, and let $\eta_m$
be a Lipschitz function of the form
$$
\eta_m(\xi)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad \xi\leqslant m,\\
\xi-m, \quad \xi>m.
\end{cases}
$$
It is clear that $\eta_m(v)\in H^1(Q_T)$ while $\eta_m(v)_{S_T}=0$ for any solution $v$. 
Taking in $(1)$ the test function $\varphi=\eta_m(v)$  yields
$$
\int\limits_{Q_T}\frac{\partial\,}{\partial t}\Phi_m(v)\,dxdt+
\int\limits_{Q_T}\eta'_m(v)|\nabla v|^2dxdt=0\tag{2}
$$
due to the chain rule $\nabla\varphi=\eta'_m(v)\nabla v$, where a nonnegative 
function $\Phi_m$ is defined as
$$
\Phi_m(\xi)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad \xi\leqslant m,\\
\frac{1}{2}(\xi-m)^2, \quad \xi>m.
\end{cases}
$$
But $\,\Phi_m(v)|_{t=0}=0$, hence by $(2)$ follows
$$
\int\limits_{\Omega}\Phi_m\bigl(v(\cdot,T)\bigr)\,dx+\int\limits_{Q_T}|\nabla
\eta_m(v)|^2dxdt=0$$
since $\eta'_m=(\eta'_m)^2$. Therefore $\nabla \eta_m(v)=0\,$ *a.e.*  in $Q_T$
which implies that $\eta_m(v)=C(t)\,$ *a.e.*  in $Q_T\,$. 
But $\eta_m(v)|_{S_T}=0$, *i.e.*, $\,C(t)=0\,$ *a.e.*  in $(0,T)\,$, 
and hence $\eta_m(v)=0\,$ *a.e.*  in $Q_T\,$. The latter implies 
the **weak essential maximum principle** 
$$
\underset{Q_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{v}\leqslant m=\underset{\Gamma_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{v}
\tag{3}
$$
with the essential supremum taken over the cylinder $Q_T\,$ *w.r.t.*  the 
$(n+1)$-dimensional Lebesgue mesure. To establish
$$
\underset{\Gamma_T}{\rm ess\,inf\,}{v}\leqslant\underset{Q_T}{\rm ess\,inf\,}{v}
\tag{4}
$$
it suffices to substitute $v$ in $(3)$ by $-v$. Inequalities $(3)$ and $(4)$ yield
the **weak essential maximum principle for the modulus**
$$
\underset{Q_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{|v|}\leqslant\underset{\Gamma_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{|v|}
\tag{5}
$$
To estimate solution $w$, notice that it can be constructed using Duhamel's principle,
*i.e.*, in the form
$$
w(x,t)=\int\limits_0^t h(x,t,\tau)\,d\tau
$$
with function $h=h(x,s,\tau)$  defined for every $\tau\in (0,T)$ with finite norm
$\|f(\cdot,\tau)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}$ as solution of the intial boundary value problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
h_{s}-\Delta h=0\;\;\text{in}\;\;\Omega\times (\tau,T)\,,\\
h|_{\partial\Omega}=0,\quad s\in [\tau,T],\\
h|_{s=0}=f(x,\tau),\quad x\in\overline{\Omega}.
\end{cases}
$$
Otherwise, *i.e.*, for $\tau\in (0,T)$ with the infinite norm
$\|f(\cdot,\tau)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\,$, a zero option $h(\cdot,\cdot,\tau)=0$ 
is chosen without loss of generality. Hence for almost every $s\in (\tau,T)$ by $(5)$ follows
$$
\underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{|h(\cdot,s,\tau)|}
\leqslant\underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{|f(\cdot,\tau)|}
$$
for almost all $\tau\in (0,s)$, whence follows
$$
\underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}|w(\cdot,t)|\leqslant
\int\limits_0^t \underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}|h(\cdot,t,\tau)|\,d\tau
\leqslant\int\limits_0^t \underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}|f(\cdot,\tau)|\,d\tau
$$
for almost all $t\in (0,T)$. For a weak solution $u\in H^1(Q_T)$ to the
inhomogeneous heat equation $u_t-\Delta u=f$, thus holds the following 
**weak essential maximum principle for the modulus**
$$
\underset{Q_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}|u|\leqslant\underset{\Gamma_T}{\rm ess\,sup\,}{|u|}
+\int\limits_0^T \underset{\Omega}{\rm ess\,sup\,}|f(\cdot,t)|\,dt.
$$

Comment: Hello, Is there other methods without using maximum principle ? Thank you.

Comment: Is there any similar result for $u_t -\Delta u + a(x) u=0$ where $a\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a classical solution, evaluate at the point of maximum of $u$. The laplacian has the appropriate sign and then you get
$$
\frac{d}{dt}\|u(t)\|_{L^\infty}\leq \|f\|_{L^\infty}.
$$
Then integrate in time.

Comment: Thanks. But you won't get classical solution (I guess we need at least $u \in C^2$ to do what you suggest) without more regularity on the data I believe.

Comment: Actually you need $C^1([0,T]\times\Omega)$ for the approximated solutions.

Comment: Such "approximated solutions" obviously require approximated data $u_0\in C^1(\Omega)$ inconsistent with $L^{\infty}$-norm unless $\,u_0\in C(\Omega)$. Besides, $u\in C^1([0,T]\times\Omega)$ is obviously not enough to decide whether the Laplacian does possess the appropriate sign.

Comment: Since $\,u|_{\partial\Omega}=0$, given any $t>0$,  a positive maximum $M(t)\overset{\rm def}{=}\underset{x\in\overline{\Omega}}{\rm max}\,u(x,t)\,$ is attained generally at some subset of interior points $\,a(t)\subset\Omega$, while $\,\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}=M(t)=u\bigl(a(t),t)\bigr)$. Despite the fact that $\nabla_x u\bigl(a(t),t\bigr)=0$, it seems unlikely that one can easily establish differentiability of a composite function $u\bigl(a(t),t\bigr)$ with a set-valued $a$. The case of a multi-valued  $M'(t)$ cannot be a priori excluded, which makes the approach overcomplicated.

Comment: Well, I don't know it it's seems unlikely or not. You can NOT establish differentiability. What you do is to prove that M(t) is Lipschitz, ergo, it is differentiable a.e.. Once you have this, you prove that $M'(t)=\partial_t u(x_t,t)$. Of course that $M(t)$ may be attained in more than one point, however, this is not relevant since at every point will decay. This "overcomplicated" approach is widely spread (check this, for instance, http://www.uam.es/personal_pdi/ciencias/acordoba/documentos/articulos/QuasiGeostrophicEquations.pdf)

Comment: Concerning you comment on the sign of the laplacian: the approximate solution will be as smooth as you want, isn't it? 

However, the problem with the boundary is pertinent. Even if you mollify the initial $L^\infty$ data (which gives you $C^1$ function with the appropriate $L^\infty$ bound) there is a problem close to the boundary.

Comment: Thanx for the link. Very interesting. "Overcomplicated" refers just to the necessity of going deep inside into the set-valued analysis, which amounts to something like inadequate use of force. The question is much simpler.

Comment: @guacho, the link of the paper not working for me, thank you for an available link.

Comment: This is the reference I mentioned



“A maximum principle applied to quasi-geostrophic equations.”
A. Córdoba, D. Córdoba Comm. Math. Phys., 249 (2004), no. 3, 511-528

As I said, there are many other references that use this technique, so you can probably find many more.