# $L^\infty$ bound on solution of $u_t -\Delta u =f$ where $f \in L^\infty$ and $u_0 \in L^\infty$??

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, maximum-principle, bochner-spaces

Let $u_0 \in L^\infty(\Omega)$ and $f \in L^\infty((0,T)\times\Omega)$ and consider
$$u_t - \Delta u = f$$
$$u(0) = u_0$$
with some boundary conditions.  Consider the weak form

$$\int_{\Omega}u_t\varphi + \int_{\Omega}\nabla u \nabla \varphi = \int_{\Omega}f\varphi $$

How can I show that $u \in {L^\infty((0,T)\times \Omega)}$ or $u \in {L^\infty(0,T;L^\infty(\Omega))}$, **without using classical approach** (just a weak approach)?

If the classical theory cannot be avoid then I don't mind using it. I would have thought we should test with $(u(t) - \Vert u_0 \Vert_{L^\infty})^+$ but don't know what do with the term involving $f$.

Comment: See the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/776017/bounded-data-means-bounded-solution-to-parabolic-pde/804099#804099

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider some $v(t) = \alpha t + \beta$. Then $v(t)$ will satisfy
$$
v_t - \Delta v = \alpha,\\
v(0) = \beta.
$$
Take now $\alpha$ such that $\alpha \geq f$ in $(0, T)\times \Omega$ and $\beta$ such that $\beta \geq u(0)$. (it is possible due to the boundedness of $f$ and $u_0$).

Therefore, the Weak maximum principle for $w = v - u$ will give you that $w \geq 0$. Hence, $u \leq v$, but $v$ is bounded (for $T < +\infty$). Thus, $u$ is also bounded.

Comment: However, I realised that this approach is classical (

Comment: Thanks. Can we not just do what you suggest in the weak formulation, and it still works if I am right? I don't think we need classical solutions???

Comment: @riem Yes, you are right. The weak maximum principle can be proved for weak solutions using the way you suggested.

Comment: @Voliar: You forget about "some boundary conditions". Besides, it is not just the boundedness, it is the essential boundedness.

Comment: @mkl314 Thanks! But I think it is obvious, since $v$ depends only on $t$...

Comment: @Voliar: $\dots\,$. But not $u$, and hence $w$. And how the boundary condition $u|_{\partial\Omega}=\psi$ is to be incorporated into this approach?

Comment: @mkl314 Oh yeah, you are right! I'll think about it.

Comment: @mkl314 riem wrote that there are some boundary conditions (but he say nothing about their boundedness). If such conditions are bounded, then the approach works. If boundary conditions are unbounded (probably, it is possible), then we cannot prove $L^\infty$-estimate.

Comment: @Voliar Sorry can I ask what the matter is with $w$ depending on $t$ *and* $x$ (you and mkl314 were disagreeing about something but I can't see what exactly)

Comment: @LapLace In approach which I suggested we need to take additionally $\alpha$ and $\beta$ big enough to make $v(t)$ greater than "some boundary conditions" (which must be specified, of course).  After that the Weak maximum principle works as usual.   (I hope, I understand your question correctly)

Comment: @Voliar Oh thanks. I have a manifold without boundary so nothing for me to worry about :)

Comment: Hello @Voliar, is there any method without using maximum principle ? What about the equation $u_t =\Delta u + a(x)u$ where $a$ is essentially bounded ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @S.Cho Unfortunately, I don't know a way how to avoid the usage of maximum or comparison principles here...

Comment: Okey, thank you.